# How can I use ANTLR to automate source code navigation?

Tags: c#, python, antlr

I'd like my app to have a basic understanding of source codes of multiple languages in order to automate code navigation.

- E.g. I want it to understand that some text is a **variable**, that the variable is of a certain **type** and that the type is defined in a specific **file**.
- I don't want to define grammars myself, I'd like to use some open source tools

From what I understand I need a lexer / tokenizer.

After a little bit of research, I found ANTLR, which has quite a few [grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) already defined.

I'd like to accomplish the 3 goals:

1. Provide grammar file for language X
2. Provide some source code for language X
3. Get the tokenized code, so I can navigate it

My preferred technology is C#, but Python for even some hybrid approach with docker embedded ANTLR would also be fine.

Can anyone provide me with a quick-start example?

ANTLR even has a C# port: [ANTLRCS](https://github.com/antlr/antlrcs). I cannot find any examples of how to use it though.

If there are better approaches than using ANTLR, please do not hesitate to share :)

Comment: You are making the mistake of assuming that 1) if you have a parser, you can get useful type information *easily*, 2) that the you have accurate source location information and 3) that the grammars operate in similar way so one tool can treat them similarly.    See my essay on Life After Parsing: https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Comment: Stackoverflow is not well suited for "a quick-start example" (the internet is full of that). I recommend you to do some research yourself, and try to do what you outline. If you get stuck along the way, feel free to ask a specific question on SO. Good luck!

Comment: @BartKiers I tried to play around with ANTLRCS, but got stuck like immediately. There's literally no docs about the workflow nor working examples/tutorials I could find on the web. Maybe I used bad keywords, but honestly, I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: 1) Even if your app is in C#, you should be able to use Java ANTLR (the generator) and only set it to generate the *parser itself* in C# (i.e. C# being the target language, not the language the tool itself is written in): https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/CSharp

Comment: 2) It's not enough to tokenize the input for your purposes - variable name and type name are both just *identifier*s to the lexer. So you need the full parser, not just lexer.